# remove first half of string but keep second half in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently [created my own personal portal page](http://caffeinecreations.ca/blog/rolling-my-own-igoogle-replacement-using-craftcms) to replace iGoogle since it's going to be shuttered later this year. Everything is working fine except that one of the RSS feeds that I'm pulling in outputs urls that look like this: http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNFEguC5pqagsWkkW_y_EjYj9n1bMg&url=http://www.haaretz.com/news/diplomacy-defense/israel-to-un-replace-austrian-peacekeepers-withdrawn-from-golan-1.528305

Which when clicked go to a bad url page. How would I remove the first half of that url so that it only has the part starting from the second http://

Strange, but here the link works fine...

Just realized the issue is that somehow the ampersands are being turned into entities which is breaking the links...

Answer (score 0):

---

### Edit: Code updated, jsFiddle added

---

**HTML:**

```
<input id="schnitzel" type="text" value="http://www.google.com/http://www.real-foo.bar/" />
<input type="button" onclick="$('#schnitzel').val(window.firstHTTP($('#schnitzel').val()));" value="&raquo;" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.firstHTTP = function (furl = "") {
    var chunked = furl.split("http://");
    return (chunked && chunked[2]) ? ("http://" + chunked[2]) : furl;
};
```

**JS-Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/Rm5bU/

Comment: copied and pasted as is into my scripts.js file and no go. also put inside a document ready function with no results. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. A generic approach.

```
function queryString(parameter, url) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;        
    var loc = decodeURIComponent(a.search.substring(1, a.search.length));
    var param_value = false;
    var params = loc.split("&");

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        param_name = params[i].substring(0, params[i].indexOf('='));
        if (param_name == parameter) {
            param_value = params[i].substring(params[i].indexOf('=') + 1)
        }
    }

    if (param_value) {
        return encodeURIComponent(param_value);
    }
    else {
        return "";
        //param not found
    }
}

var secondHTTP = queryString("url", 'http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNFEguC5pqagsWkkW_y_EjYj9n1bMg&url=http://www.haaretz.com/news/diplomacy-defense/israel-to-un-replace-austrian-peacekeepers-withdrawn-from-golan-1.528305');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "http://news.google.com/news/url?sa=t&fd=R&usg=AFQjCNFEguC5pqagsWkkW_y_EjYj9n1bMg&url=http://www.haaretz.com/news/diplomacy-defense/israel-to-un-replace-austrian-peacekeepers-withdrawn-from-golan-1.528305";

var url = decodeURIComponent(str.split(/https?:/ig).pop());
```

will result in

```
"//www.haaretz.com/news/diplomacy-defense/israel-to-un-replace-austrian-peacekeepers-withdrawn-from-golan-1.528305"
```

---

or

```
var url = decodeURIComponent(str.match(/^http.+(http.+)/i)[1]);
```

will result in

```
"http://www.haaretz.com/news/diplomacy-defense/israel-to-un-replace-austrian-peacekeepers-withdrawn-from-golan-1.528305"
```

Comment: This looks to be the simplest approach, but I'm not sure where to put this. I dropped the code into my scripts.js file and no go. I then wrapped the code in a document ready function which also didn't work. Sorry my javascript skill is still very elementary.